# Change position of main Header in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Is it possible to replace the positions of main header and group header in crystal report

[Picture link because i cant place image](http://tinypic.com/r/301fr86/8)

I want to move Group Header #1: command.TIP - A up one place so the order would be.

```
Report Header
Group header.
Page header
Details 
...
.
.
```

Im trying to put the details Name

Example i have to group users by Town

currently i have

```
Name           LastName     Age
               TESTTOWN
Anel            Bavarac     23
Test            User        24
               TESTTOWN2
Anel            Bavarac     23
Test            User        24
```

All i want to do is to replace first two lines

```
               TESTTOWN
Name           LastName     Age

Anel            Bavarac     23
```

Comment: what are you trying to put in page header?

Comment: @Siva thanks on your  answer i have just updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need page header to be replaced, just supress the page header then insert one more sectiom for group as group header 1a and place fields there